# Compile error when using local cshtml files in CloudScribe SimpleContent

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, cloudscribe

I'm 'skinning' the blog engine SimpleContent by Cloudscribe, and have copied locally the necessary partial views to give me editorial control over the html. There are two views which give me an error when running, namely ArvhieListPartial.cshtml and CategoryListPartial.cshtml.

The error is the same in both, and not present in any other blog related cshtml pages:

```
<li>
    <a asp-route="@blogRoutes.BlogArchiveRouteName"
        asp-route-year="@cat.Key.Substring(0,4)"
        asp-route-month="@cat.Key.Substring(5,2)">@cat.Key.Replace("/", "-")(@cat.Value)</a>
</li>
```

`@cat.Key` is the error point, the browser reports:

> Non-invocable member KeyValuePair<string, int>. Key cannot be used like a method.

I notice that these two partial views are the only ones which have references at the top like this:

```
@model Dictionary<string, int>
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 version 15.2 (26430.16)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is because you removed the space between these

```
@cat.Key.Replace("/", "-")(@cat.Value)
```

the original view has a space there but by removing it razor is interpreting the ( like the beginning of a method signature instead of as literal text as it is intended to be, and since it is just a string property it throws this error because it interprets that you are using it like a method

Comment: Brilliant, answer is perfect. To find out how the space disappeared, I repeated what I did which was to copy the 'markup' from ArchiveListPartial.cshtml and paste it into my own empty file ArchiveListPartial.cshtml - Visual Studio took out that space again. Same happened in CategoryListPartial. When I'm up and running I'll make up a little article with this and other discoveries. Thanks again, loving the code